# How to align a 'div' element horizontally according to another 'div' element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two 'div' elements.The first one changes its position dymanically when the window(browser's window) is resized(including dragging the borders of the window). The other one is static and doesn't move.I can not put them in the same div because they are in two different files that get loaded in the same page as partial views.

I know that you probably want to see the divs themselves and the styles applied to them but I don't kno if I won't get it even more messed up for explaining.

I was just wondering if it is possible by JavaScript or whatever to get the position(and more specially the horizontal positioning) of an existing 'div' element and assign it to another so whenever I resize the window the second 'div' gets situated according to the other one?

EDIT : I am pretty much sure that I have to change the 'offsetLeft' property of the second 'div', because when I resize the window this is what dynamically changes in the first one's properties.

Comment: Dont know if I understood your problem correctly but can you try floating both divs?

Comment: Simply said: I need to know when the offsetLeft of the first 'div' has changed so then I can fire an event which will update the offsetLeft to the other 'div'. I don't know if it is possible.I am just wondering.

Comment: Of course it is possible, you can extrapolate my example below to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Isn't this why we use percentages on `<div>` widths isn't it? So whatever the browser resize, it'll be relative, no matter what's in the child elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery and you can retrieve all kinds of information about the positioning of elements, quite easily.

A great piece of jquery that will do this, is the `$.position()` function:

http://api.jquery.com/position/

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cQ4aX/1/

Comment: This works but when I want to dynamically change the position of the first 'div' I dont have a clear idea how is this going to happen.E.g.: I can get the current positioning of and element in the javascript like that: window.onload{function(){  ...  }} but when I resize the browser's window there is no event that can be fired. The page is ready and loaded and it doesn't get there for a second time so I can retrieve the new element alignment and assign it to the first 'div'.

Comment: @mathinvalidnik `$( window ).resize(function() { /** Code **/ });` !

Comment: Thank you @MackieeE ! I used the window.onresize which I guess is the same.Do you have any idea if the .position() has a public setter so I can set the 'left' or 'top' through the Method?

Comment: @mathinvalidnik: use the `$.css()` function, that will allow you to manipulate the positioning.